# combobox default value, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a combobox that populates from a database column but when the form loads, the combobox appears with the first item on the database. the value of this particular combobox determines the value of some other controls on the form so i want the combobox to load with an empty entry. thanks as i'll appreciate any help i can get.
here is my code:

```
'all variables declared...
 connection.Open()
 command = New MySqlCommand("SELECT PUMP FROM test.pump", connection)
 dataadapter.SelectCommand = command
 dataadapter.Fill(dataset)

    With Me.PumpComboBox


        .DisplayMember = "pump"
        .DataSource = dataset

    End With
```

Comment: Most simple `combobox1.selectedindex=0`

Comment: If you set the DataSource member then it is not going to be empty.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: @nelek .selectedindex = 0 only makes the combobox list empty

Comment: @Hans Passant, I noticed, how else can i go about this?

Comment: @Hans Passant, I noticed, how else can i go about this?

Comment: No real idea what you have in mind.  Consider an Edit button.

Comment: @HansPassant i just want the combobox to appear empty until user selects a value.

Comment: This is going in circles.  I'm guessing that the *real* problem is that you have an event handler for that ComboBox and it also runs when the form gets loaded with data.  Thus screwing up the displayed data.  You must prevent that from happening.  You need a Boolean field in your class.  Say, LoadingData.  Set it to True when you load the dbase record, False afterwards.  And modify the event handler to check this variable.

Comment: If you are using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to trigger a cascading effect (modify the properties of other controls), you could switch to `SelectionChangeCommitted`, which is raised only when a user changes the current item. It won't be raised when you set the `DataSource`, modifying the `Items` list. If you move the code in the event in a method, you can also easily call that method from  anywhere else, if it can useful/required somewhere else. If you don't want to show any pre-selection after a `DataSource` is modified, you can set the `SelectedIndex` to -1 without direct consequences.

Comment: Have you considered adding an empty element? select null union select ...

Comment: i added .selectedIndex = -1 and it worked fine. thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

This sets the value of the combo box to a blank entry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding empty value and then selected that empty value using selectedindex after the combbobox populated will work

Answer (score 0):

In your Form.Load include the following:

`ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1`

Here "ComboBox1" is your ComboBox and "1" equals index you want to be set by default.